# Can access internet but cannot ping

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to clone the mono repository from github. I used

`sudo git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git`

but the operation timed out. I then decided to test my connection using

`ping github.com`

and received a ICMP redirect network message. I received the same thing when I tried to ping Google. Strange thing is I can access (and search in) Google through the browser on the pi and can ssh to the pi over my local network.

Does anyone know what might be going on? I've never seen anything like this before!

Thanks!

Comment: Post the output from `sudo iptables -L`.

Answer (score -2):

This is not really a RPi problem. Connect the Ethernet cable to your computer and try if this situation persists. If so, you have a network intruder or configuration error on other networking devices. Check them and maybe contact a network security expert to kick those intruders out. If your computer works fine then check your network configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` and make sure it is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! While we are glad you are joining in on the conversation, this answer is a bit vague and lacks supporting information. If you could include some more explanation of the actual steps (such as how to check your network configuration) that would be better. Thanks!